# highland.js async array to stream of values

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highland.js

I am trying to get the following snippets to return the same output - a stream of array values.

The first method starts from an array and emits the values.

The second method gets as an input a promise that resolves an array, so instead of emiting each of the values, it only emits the array itself.

What should i change in the second method to make it output the same thing as the first?

```
const h = require('highland');

var getAsync = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve([1,2,3,4,5]);
  });
}

h([1,2,3,4,5])
  .each(console.log)
  .tap(x => console.log('>>', x))
  .done();
 //outputs 5 values, 1,2,3,4,5


h(getAsync())
  .tap(x => console.log('>>', x))
  .done();
//outputs >>[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: You used each in the first case, not in the second.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases you don't need to invoke `done`, since `each` is already consuming your stream.

The case with promise will pass the resolved value (i.e. an array of numbers) down the stream. You can use `series` method to turn each array in this stream into it's own stream and then concatenate the streams. It's a little counterintuitive in this example, as there is only one array, and thus only one stream to be concatenated. But that's what you want - a stream of numbers.

Here is the code:

```
const h = require('highland');

var getAsync = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve([1,2,3,4,5]);
  });
}

h([1,2,3,4,5])                      // stream of five numbers
  .each(console.log)                // consumption

h(getAsync())                       // stream of one array
  .series()                         // stream of five numbers
  .each(x => console.log('>>', x))  // consumption
```